# Firebase Function query and update a single Firestore document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update a user's firestore doc from a Firebase Function using a query, and having issues getting it to work. My Function code is the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * A webhook handler function for the relevant Stripe events.
 */

// Here would be the function that calls updatePlan and passes it the customer email,
// I've omitted it to simplify the snippet


const updatePlan = async (customerEmail) => {

  await admin.firestore()
    .collection('users').where('email', '==', customerEmail).get()
    .then((doc) => {
      const ref = doc.ref;
      ref.update({ 'purchasedTemplateOne': true });
    });
};
```

I'm getting the following error in the firebase logs when the query is run:

> Exception from a finished function: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')

Any help regarding what I may be doing wrong or suggestions on how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

I was able to solve my problem with more understanding of Firestore Queries:

```
const updatePlan = (customerEmail) => {

  const customerQuery = admin.firestore().collection("users").where("email", "==", customerEmail)
  customerQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      // Get just the one customer/user document
      const snapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0]
      // Reference of customer/user doc
      const documentRef = snapshot.ref
      documentRef.update({ 'purchasedTemplateOne': true })
      functions.logger.log("User Document Updated:", documentRef);
    }
    else {
      functions.logger.log("User Document Does Not Exist");
    }
  })

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `doc.ref` is undefined.  There is no property `ref` on the object `doc`.

This is probably because you misunderstand the object that results from a Firestore query.  Even if you are expecting a single document, a filtered query can return zero or more documents.  Those documents are always represented in an object of type [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).  That's what `doc` actually is - a QuerySnapshot - so you need to treat it as such.

Perhaps you should check the [size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size) of the result set before you access the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) array to see what's returned by the query. This is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

Comment: Thanks for your help Doug, I was able to solve my issue after reading over your shared docs on QuerySnapshot. I've updated my question to share the code.